# Getting seg fault 11 in sprintf

Tags: c

```
char* msg;
msg = (char*)malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %s %s %s %s %s", 
    allClients[i]->IP, allClients[i]->hostName, allClients[i]->port, 
    allClients[i]->msgSentCount, allClients[i]->msgRecvCount, allClients[i]->status) + 1);
sprintf(msg, "%s %s %s %s %s %s", 
    allClients[i]->IP, allClients[i]->hostName, allClients[i]->port, 
    allClients[i]->msgSentCount, allClients[i]->msgRecvCount, allClients[i]->status);

printf("%s\n", "here");
eachClientData[i+1] = msg;
printf("list msg: %s\n", msg);
free(msg);
```

I am getting seg fault 11 at sprintf() cause the next printf is never executed. Have I done something wrong with the malloc? Is there any upper limit to which I can add to msg?

**NOTE:** The snprintf executed fine as I had a printf after that which was executed. Also, I can give you the sizes of each of the variables I am trying to concatenate if required.

Comment: But OP has added that `+ 1` to malloc's argument.

Comment: I have 1 added at the end of malloc(). You are saying that it's overflowing by 1?

Comment: Code is having trouble yet does not check the return values of `snprintf()` nor `malloc()`.  Those would be good 1st steps.

Comment: @chux: Yep. Just did that. snprintf returns 49.

Comment: why `printf("%s\n", "here");`?  why didn't you just `printf("here");` Also, `allClients` is properly allocated? You may be accessing an invalid item from this array...

Comment: I'm not sure if modifying printf() is gonna help me anyhow. And snprintf doesn't return -1. So it is working.

Comment: I just printed all the variables I am concatenating:
allClients[i]->IP = "192.168.1.179" (without the quotes)
allClients[i]->hostName = "myhome" (without quotes) 
allClients[i]->port = 4322, 
allClients[i]->msgSentCount = 0 
allClients[i]->msgRecvCount = 0
allClients[i]->status = "logged-in" (without quotes)

Comment: Maybe you could create a MVCE for us - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - It is kind of hard to find a solution guessing...

Comment: @Leonardo Alves Machado: Any chance that you might be able to help me with the values that I provided above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing in both `int` and `string` inputs to `snprintf()` and `sprintf()`, you need to change `"%s %s %s %s %s %s"` to `"%s %s %d %d %d %s"` in order to properly handle `int` values.

Comment: Still getting a seg fault. Port is a string BTW. So it should be `%s %s %s %d %d %s`. I just corrected it. `snprintf`is returning 39. But still seg fault at `sprintf`. :(

Comment: Don't leaving us hanging then, show us how you've defined `allClients` (specifically its class or struct).

Comment: I am so sorry. It worked. It worked! THANK YOU!

Comment: I had made the change from %s to %d in snprintf and not in sprintf. Sorry about that. I am coding a chatapp in C as an assignment and this is the first time ever that I am coding in C. Like, first time. :O 
It actually worked. Thank you for noticing.

Comment: Aha, to avoid such cases, you could store the format string as `const char* formatStr = "%s %s %s %d %d %s"`, then use `formatStr` in `snprintf()` and `sprintf()`. This way you'd only need to change a single string if you'd like to update the format.

Comment: Okay. That sounds neat. I don't know any of the nuances in C. I should have known that just knowing Java isn't gonna help much before I took the networking course. :( Anyhow, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

`allClients[i]->port` (and some other variables) look like integers. You cannot print them with `%s`; that is for strings. What happens is that the `%s` format makes the `sprintf` read the memory behind the adress that the `int` contains, 0x000010e2, as 0x10e2 = 4322, and then continue reading from there until it finds a `’\0’`, as it thinks it is processing a string. This is undefined behavior.

Use `%d` instead, or `%ld` if it is a long int, etc.